# What is the Objective-C equivalent for "toString()", for use with NSLog?

Tags: objective-c, tostring, nslog

Is there a method that I can override in my custom classes so that when

```
      NSLog(@"%@", myObject)
```

is called, it will print the fields (or whatever I deem important) of my object?  I guess I'm looking for the Objective-C equivalent of Java's `toString()`.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

It is the `description` instance method, declared as:

```
- (NSString *)description
```

Here's an example implementation (thanks to grahamparks):

```
- (NSString *)description {
   return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Photo: Name=%@ Author=%@", name, author];
}
```

Comment: Note if you're using CoreData, the `description` property [is reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717519/why-cant-i-use-description-as-an-attribute-name-for-a-core-data-entity) ...and will provide useful debugging information! In that case you'll need to come up with your own unique method name.

Comment: Is `debugDescription` also reserved? Although I think `DebugDescription` is supposed to be used by a debugger like LLDB.

Answer (score 37):

Add this to the `@implementation` of your Photo class:

```
- (NSString *)description {
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photo: Name=%@ Author=%@",name,author];
}
```

Answer (score 25):

You can override the description method of NSObject:

```
- (NSString *)description
```

On the subject of logging I recommend this [blog post](http://blog.mbcharbonneau.com/2008/10/27/better-logging-in-objective-c/) for better logging in Objective-C.

Comment: Isn't this a static method?  I'd like this to operate on objects rather than the class.  For example, if I have a "Photo" class, with fields "name" and "author", I'd like NSLog to print those fields as they are assigned in the object.

Comment: Yes - well spotted - I pressed the wrong key. I clearly should pay more attention when proof reading my answers. Thankfully someone had their eye on the ball :-)

Answer (score 13):

There are two functions that you can use.

```
- (NSString*)description
```

This will be displayed when you put your object as, I.E. a parameter for `NSLog`. The other description function is:

```
- (NSString*)debugDescription
```

This will be called when you do `po anInstanceOfYourClass` in the debug command window. If your class doesn't have a `debugDescription` function, then just `description` will be called.

Note that the base class `NSObject` does have `description` implemented, but it is fairly bare-bones: it only displays the address of the object. This is why I recommend that you implement `description` in any class you want to get info out of, especially if you use the `description` method in your code. If you do use `description` in your code, I suggest you implement `debugDescription` as well, also making `debugDescription` more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

This will output the available voices:

```
    NSLog((@"speechVoices:%", [[AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices] description] ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think comment from @Nuthatch of overriding "description" with CoreData (i.e classes inheriting NSManagedObject) should be emphasized

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject?language=objc

> Avoid overriding description—if this method fires a fault during a
> debugging operation, the results may be unpredictable.