# Dumping contents of Array Obj-c to consoler

Tags: iphone, printing, nsmutablearray

I looked for how to dump and array to the console I have mostly found:

```
for (id name in arrayStuff)
    NSLog (@"Array contents:  %d", name);
```

I've tried different formaters %d %@ %g etc. which does print different stuff, but not the values I'm 99% sure are being entered into the object and consequently the array.  This doesn't seem to work, how would you know what to use as the formater?

I have an NSMutableArray with instance of an object containing one int and two doubles added to the array in each loop.  I would like to print those values out and make sure the correct ones are going in.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format specifier is wrong. NSArrays contain objects, not ints, so you have to use the specifier for Objective-C objects `%@`:

```
for (id name in arrayStuff)
    NSLog(@"Array element: %@", name);
```

Or just:

```
NSLog(@"Array contents: %@", arrayStuff);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the "%@" format specifier for printing objects.

To have the contents of your object displayed (the int & doubles), you need to implement the `-description` method in your object.

See [What is the Objective-C equivalent for "toString()", for use with NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104746/what-is-the-objective-c-equivalent-for-tostring-for-use-with-nslog)

Answer (score 1):

If you've created an Object type to hold the values, then use that object type in your for loop, and then use the getter to access the objects:

```
for (ObjectName name in arrayStuff) {
    NSLog(@"Array int: %d", name.myIntValue);
    NSLog(@"Array double: %f ...
}
```