# Realm `description` property behaving differently to other properties

Tags: ios, realm

Normally when you `NSLog` a Realm object you get something like:

```
MPWidget {
    identifier: 5,
    title: "My widget",
    cost: 38
}
```

However, if a Realm object has a `description` property I just see the `description` printed instead. Just the description, no other properties or inkling that it's a Realm object.

Is this a feature or a bug? Is it documented anywhere? And lastly, can I turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating a `description` property, you're overriding the `-description` method on NSObject that's used to print an object's contents when using `NSLog` or `println`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4718806/373262 for more details.