# Objective-C - NSLog - "%@" Referencing Character

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I'm working through a BNR iOS Programming text and I came across this piece of code:

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [items objectAtIndex:i]);
```

I am unsure of what "%@" is used for. I've seen other formats for referencing integers or characters, but I've never seen this.

I even checked this reference [here](http://blog.teliaz.com/2010/objective-c-basic-datatypes-and-nslog) and it had nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not look at Apple's docs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265  rather than a random blog

Comment: You want the [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

%@ is for printing objective-c objects.

To be a bit more precise. Every object is able to override

```
-(NSString *)description
```

This method is called when you use %@. It depends on the object what info of the object it will return in the `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple:

> Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by `descriptionWithLocale:` if available, or `description` otherwise. Also works with `CFTypeRef` objects, returning the result of the `CFCopyDescription` function.

Reference:

- [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)

Answer (score 0):

I am working through the same text - and coming from a Java background, the "%@" formatter seems equivalent to the "toString" method that Java would have.
It is used to display custom information about an object.

There is a good example in the response to this StackOverflow [question about the "toString()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104746/what-is-the-objective-c-equivalent-for-tostring-for-use-with-nslog) equivalent.