# How do i print out the contents of an Object that is stored in an array, instead of something that looks like this <(Object Name): 0x10010ff10>?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, nslog

I create the instance of the Object 'Event' then add it to the array called eventsStore.

```
Event *event = [[Event alloc] init];
 event.courseName = @"Maths";
 event.room = @"405";
 event.startTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:9];
 event.endTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
[eventsStore addObject:event];
```

I can see in the debugger when I run it that all the information is stored but when I try to `NSLog` the information back out using:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [eventsStore objectAtIndex:i]);
```

The only thing that shows up `<Event: 0x10010ff10>`. How can I print out the whole contents of the Event?

Comment: Try to override the `description` methode.

Comment: Have you tried to check the `description` method ?

Answer (score 1):

To get a more detailed output when using this kind of `NSLog`, you can override the `- (NSString *)description` method of your `NSObject` subclass. See also this question: [What is the Objective-C equivalent for "toString()", for use with NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104746/what-is-the-objective-c-equivalent-for-tostring-for-use-with-nslog)

Comment: Minor nitpick but you override the `description` method of the class, not the object.

Comment: You are correct, fixed this. :)