# How to get value in NSCoding?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to study the work of NSCoding. I successfully created a sample. Here's what I have done. I create a read button. here are the codes

```
- (IBAction)readBtn:(id)sender {

    self.cars.name = @"honda";
    self.cars.color = @"blue";

    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.cars];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"cars"];

}
```

and I create another button for write

```
- (IBAction)writeBtn:(id)sender {


    NSData *datas = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"cars"];
    NSArray *books = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:datas];


    NSLog(@"array %@",books);
}
```

When I click the write button. why is it the output of my array is like this

```
array <Car: 0x7ff65bc44e50>
```

not the value of **honda** and **blue**.

Comment: FYI - your read and write are backwards.

Comment: And the data you unarchive is not an array.

Comment: If you want different output when you log a `Car` instance, implement the `description` method in your `Car` class.

Comment: You need to implement `-description`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104746/what-is-the-objective-c-equivalent-for-tostring-for-use-with-nslog

Comment: sorry guys, I'm new here. I will check first the link. thanks

Comment: "Member for 2 years, 4 months" :P